# Is there a way to embed Visual Studio Online team rooms into Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

My team currently makes full use of Visual Studio Online team rooms to see when code is pushed to the server as well as track the chatter around it. I find having chatter in this environment keeps it on a more professional level.

In Visual Studio 2013 we were using a plugin to have this team rooms display directly within the Visual Studio application. Unfortunately this is no longer working with Visual Studio 2015 and I was wondering if there's a method for doing this out of the box that potentially I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, The us no way to get rid of of the box. You may want to email The Developers of the Plug-In that you were using and get them to update it.